# Send verification emails in Meteor without accounts-password

Tags: meteor

On my Meteor site, users can log in using an OAuth authentication from a particular provider (vKontakte). After logging in, on a special page of my site users can specify also their email address to receive notifications. Obviously, I want to verify the address before any notification sent.

Standard instructions for email verification that I find in Meteor docs and in other sites use `accounts-password` package. That's OK, and I can call `sendVerificationEmail()` from my email update code, but the problem is that `accounts-password` also adds possibility for local (non-OAuth) registration. My site is rather tightly coupled with the OAuth provider, so I do not want to have any other way to login to my site except via this OAuth provider, and so I do not want to have `accounts-password` package on my site. Or at least I want `accounts-password` to have no effect from the user point of view except the possibility to send verification emails (no register buttons etc.)

Is there any way to send verification emails without `accounts-password` package? Or to disable all `accounts-password` functionality except email verification?

Of course, I can implement email verification completely manually (generate a token, send an email, setup a route for verification), but if there is some more standard way to do this, I'd better stick to it.

Comment: I want to solve this exact same problem, had any progress so far? I also disagree adding the accounts-password and solving it with CSS.

Comment: @flowen, I've added my "solution" as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by copying the `accounts-password.js` file to `server/lib` and removing all code that I did not need. I do not like this solution because if `accounts-password` wil be updated, I will have to update my file manually, but I see no other way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was afraid of doing something similar. Perhaps someone with sufficient skills (I do not) can create a package for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that all of what you are describing is needed. Granted, the code would exist on the server, but if you were to add `accounts-password` and call `sendVerificationEmail()` there is really nothing to say that you will have to have the signup and password functionality that it allows. Are you using the accounts-ui-unstyled to handle the front end portion of the accounts? If so, you can simply not give the user the ability to see or use the functionality you don't want them to have.

Comment: Yes, I am using `accounts-ui` to provide ui for OAuth signin, so when I add `accounts-password`, in the sign-in popup email and password fields appear, which I do not want. How can I reliably make user not see and use this functionality?

Comment: If I were you I would simply remove accounts-ui and add accounts-ui-unstyled. From there I would use css to hide or remove the elements I do not want. Alternatively, you can make your own account template. Basically you can use the accounts-ui template as a base example and build your own.

Comment: I don't want to remove login options only using css, because users will easily be able to enable it back. So for now I, instead of adding accounts-password, simply copied its files to my project and removed everything for password login from there, leaving email verification. This seems to be working.

Comment: I agree at least in theory, css would leave the functionality for an astute user to be able to sneak in and use. Your approach may be preferred. However, if your product is tightly tied to a Facebook login, making another login type useless from a functional standpoint means that anyone who created their own by manipulating css would only be performing an exercise in frustration.